# disable rsh on ubuntu server

Tags: services, remote-login

I installed rsh-server in my system for test purposes, but now I want to disable it without removing its package. I don't know how I can check rsh status. I can not see it with:

> sudo service rshd status

Noted that, I don't install rsh under xinetd.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Ubuntu system on my hands, but I believe its started by `xinetd`:
Edit `/etc/xinetd.d/rsh` and set **disable=yes**.

You need to restart the xinetd service once you're done.

Comment: I don;t install xinetd at all, but install rsh-server in my system. Then installed rsh-client to test rsh-server. When I run rshd localhost, I can login to my system. There is same situation for telnetd. But it is exist in /etc/inietd.conf. please see http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch16_:_Telnet,_TFTP,_and_xinetd#.VGdYM_mUdPQ

Comment: Package `rsh-server` has a dependency on `openbsd-inetd` but I can't verify this at the moment.